# Greatest Common Divisor Problem: Prove that $\gcd(\frac{a^3+b^3}{a+b}, a+b) = \gcd(a+b, 3ab)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

I've been stuck in this problem for some time now. Currently what I have accomplished is, using the propriety $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,a \bmod(b))$  to get in the equation

$$ \gcd(a+b, \frac{a^3+b^3}{a+b}\bmod(a+b)) $$

but I don't know where to go anymore or even if I'm in the correct path. Any tips or solutions would be great appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\frac{a^3+b^3}{a+b}=a^2-ab+b^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*hint*: $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2) = (a+b)((a+b)^2 -3ab)$

Answer (score 2):

We have $gcd((a^3 + b^3)/(a+b), a + b) = gcd(a^2 - ab + b^2, a + b) = gcd((a^2 - ab + b^2) - (a+b)(a+b), a + b) = gcd(-3ab, a + b) = gcd(3ab, a + b)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{a^3+b^3}{a+b} \\ a+b 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2-ab+b^2 \\ a+b 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & a+b \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3ab \\ a+b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The result follows because the matrix has determinant $-1$ and so has an integer inverse.